# Copy values and formulas to a different sheet in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to copy the full data from one sheet to another including all the values and all the formulas.  The problem I have is that I cannot find a function that does both setValues is just the values, setFormulas just the formulas.  Is there a way to combine both of these into a single copy so all the information comes across.  if it includes the formatting information that would be even better.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help? It duplicates an entire sheet?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)

and if it doesn't, could you use the copyTo function of range?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)

Comment: I am already using the .copyto method.  I am trying to find a way to do it for just a range so I can move just sections of a sheet rather than the entire sheet at the same time.  The big issue I have on moving the entire sheet is that it then includes an "importdata" statement and there are then permissions issues that have to be resolved to get it to work.

Comment: Ah, I see your edit now- I must try it with range, didn;t know there was a copyto with range!